# Socket.io not listening

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

im using this simple code

Client.html

http://pastebin.com/c1C2F9MQ

Server.js

http://pastebin.com/Cqjhjfwm

Everything working fine till the last step of my client code

```
socket.on('add', function(data) {

    socket.broadcast.emit('AAA');

});
```

It seems that the socket add never comes but on my server I have

```
socket.on('Text', function(data) {

socket.emit('add', data);
```

});

And I tested if socket text was coming and it does, I cant find the problem
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`socket.broadcast.emit` sends message to all sockets connected to server except the concerned `socket`. So most likely `add` does come to server but it broadcasts `AAA` which your client cannot get. Use `io.sockets.emit` to send to all connected sockets. Change this

```
socket.broadcast.emit('AAA');
```

to

```
io.sockets.emit('AAA');
```

#### Update

I too overlooked that you are calling `socket.broadcast.emit` from client not from server. It would have shown error on browser console, since broadcast is absent on client.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your `on('add')` code on the client side is within the `on('connect')` event which is not correct...

You need to take it ouside there, so it becomes:

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
    $('#button').click(function() {  
        var addtext = $('#text').val();
        socket.emit('Text', addtext);
    });
});

socket.on('add', function(data) {  
    socket.emit('AAA');  
});
```

**EDIT**: I also just noticed you had `socket.broadcast.emit()` in your client side code. As far as I know there's no concept of broadcasting from the client. If you want to broadcast something then the client should send it to the server then the server broadcasts to the other clients.

Comment: by the way I can see where you've got confused here - the server is different from the client in how the code is laid out. That's because your server code has to deal with many different clients, so you need a consistent socket object for each connection. The client doesn't have the issue and as such each event can be treated separately without encapsulating them in one 'connection' function.

Comment: Well I added the socket.on('add' outside the connect one but its not working.

Comment: The problem is that when I do more than 1 socket.emit the newest one wont work!

Comment: note also that you have no `socket.on('AAA')` event on the server.